# .then is not a function / Promises

Tags: javascript, promise

Got error **.then is not a function.**

When I call a function that gets some stuff aynch like this:

```
Store.BackgroundFinalizer().then(function() {
  console.log('DO ALARM when Data is there');
  alarmNextEpisode();
});
```

---

Function:

```
static BackgroundFinalizer() {
  const items = Store.getStoredItems();
  items.forEach(function (item) { // 0.1
    if (new Date(item.episode) < new Date()) {
      let tvmaze = new Tvmaze();
      tvmaze.getData(item.name).then(data => {
        tvmaze.getEpisodeData(data.data.id).then(data => {
          let newdate = tvmaze.sortByNextEpisode(data);
          Store.removeStoreItem(item.name);
          Store.storeItem2(item.name, newdate);
        });
      });
    } else {}
  });
  return 'promise'
}
```

Do I need to return a promise? Even though the function itself doesn't require one? What to do?

Comment: well `BackgroundFinalizer()` will return you a string. You cannot treat it as a Promise...if it isn't.

Comment: `return 'promise'` does not return a promise, it returns a string. What use is that? If you need to return an actual promise, return an actual promise, don't think JavaScript can figure out what you mean here.

Comment: What promise should I return ? I dont actually need anthing to return.

Comment: @Medy do you need to know when it is done?

Comment: @KevinB no I just to run alarmNextEpisode();  after getEpisodeData is done

Comment: so you *do* need to know when it's done then? you can't run x after y if you don't know when y finishes.

Comment: I see ..  so I need to return the promise of getEpisodedata().. sicne getEpisodedata() only gets called after getdata() is finished.   This is probably what i want ?

Comment: You can't return anything that's inside the .each, a function can only return one value. You'll have to collect an array of promises, then wait for all of those promises to resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [study promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) before use it.

```
static BackgroundFinalizer() {
  return new Promise ( (resolve, reject) => {
    const items = Store.getStoredItems();
    items.forEach(function (item) { // 0.1

        if (new Date(item.episode) < new Date()) {

            let tvmaze = new Tvmaze();

             tvmaze.getData(item.name).then(data => {

                return tvmaze.getEpisodeData(data.data.id);

             }).then(data => {

                     let newdate = tvmaze.sortByNextEpisode(data);
                     Store.removeStoreItem(item.name);
                     Store.storeItem2(item.name, newdate);

             });

        } else {

        }


    });

    resolve('success');
  });
}
```

Comment: @KevinB theres lots of mistake in his code, I don't want to explode my head so, he need a promise, he will get the promise. Didn't even noticed I wrote down insife a forEach. Now `forEach` callback would still be running and I would had resolved it any way.

Comment: Thanks this works.
 @Matthew Moore Solution does not.
Need to restudy this yes

Answer (score -1):

`return 'promise'` is returning the string `promise`, not a Promise. You need to create a Promise for your code, more akin to what I've done below:

(Note, I just threw this in, and don't have a full test available; there may be other issues in the code. But this should get you closer to your goal)

```js
static BackgroundFinalizer() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    const items = Store.getStoredItems();
    items.forEach(function(item) { // 0.1
      if (new Date(item.episode) < new Date()) {

        let tvmaze = new Tvmaze();

        tvmaze.getData(item.name).then(data => {

          tvmaze.getEpisodeData(data.data.id).then(data => {

            let newdate = tvmaze.sortByNextEpisode(data);
            Store.removeStoreItem(item.name);
            Store.storeItem2(item.name, newdate);

          });
        });
      } else {
   };
    });
 
 resolve();
  });
}
```